# Cannot understand this example fail2ban rule

Tags: linux, security, debian, iptables, fail2ban

I'm trying to secure my admin and user login page from brute force attacks. I have setup iptables and the closest thing I can find which looks useful is this:

jail file:

```
[nginx-login]
enabled = true
filter = nginx-login
action = iptables-multiport[name=NoLoginFailures, port="http,https"]
logpath = /var/log/nginx*/*access*.log
bantime = 600 # 10 minutes
maxretry = 6
```

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-login.conf

```
# Blocks IPs that fail to authenticate using web application's log in page.
# Scan access log for HTTP 200 + POST /sessions => failed log in.
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST /sessions HTTP/1\.." 200
ignoreregex =
```

I can't seem to understand what it is doing in this regard. First of all, a result of 200 means that the login was successful, so I can't see how it will detect invalid logins.

Can anyone explain what this code is doing and why it might be used to stop brute force logins please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to understand what it is doing in this regard. First of all, a result of 200 means that the login was successful,

No, it's just the HTTP-Status Code for `OK`. So the server hasn't encountered any problems on protocol-layer, nor had the application running on the server any serious problems (4xx and 5xx). This only means, a page will be served.

> so I can't see how it will detect invalid logins

It doesn't. It only counts how often a IP called the URL `/session` via POST (submitted a HTML-form).

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*POST /sessions HTTP/1\.." 200
```

After 6 occurrences of this line in the log (thus a user submitted the form 6 times), the user get's blocked.

```
maxretry = 6
```

The time of blocking is `bantime` and the time fail2ban looks backward is `findtime`. Both values are 600 seconds by default, so 5 minutes.

To ban only failed logins, you have to log them from your application, as the webserver does not now if a login (which is handled by the web application) failed or succeeded.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So this script is banning someone if they submit a form 6 times? Is that 6 times in a row, or six times within a set period for example?

Comment: The default for `findtime` is 600 seconds, so at maximum 6 POST-requests in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So basically this filter stops them spamming form submissions, 6 requests in 5 mins?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.